# Do we only get conics when we do the Dupin indicatrix procedure?

Tags: differential-geometry

Calculation of the Dupin Indicatrix involves taking a plane close by to the tangent plane at a point on the surface and seeing the curve intersected. This curve intersected, depending on the type of conic, we say the point which we started with is elliptical, hyperbolic , parabolic etc.

Question: Can Dupin indicatrix classify any point on any surface? i.e: Will the curve produced by this procedure ALWAYS be a conic? How to prove?

Comment: By any surface are you referring to a regular surface?

Comment: umm I do not know what regularity of a surface refers too @ArvinRasoulzadeh

Comment: There's a misunderstanding here. The Dupin indicatrix is defined to be a conic in the tangent plane at the point. It is defined in terms of the second fundamental form. The heuristic is that the intersection of the surface with nearby parallel planes "looks like" the Dupin indicatrix. Of course it will not be a conic unless the surface is itself of the form $z=Q(x,y)$ for $Q$ a quadratic polynomial. Try $z=x^2+y^4$ or $z=x^3+y^4$ or anything general.

Comment: So, really, what kind of surfaces is dupin indicatrix useful on then ? @TedShifrin

Answer (score 1):

Assume a regular surface $S$ with the parametrization
\begin{equation}
    \sigma: \left(u,v\right) \longmapsto \left(\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\right).
\end{equation}
Furthermore, let $N$ be the unit normal to $S$. If $T_p\,S$ is tangent to the surface at the point $p$ and $q = \sigma(u + du, v + dv)$ is another point on the surface, then the distance from $q$ to $T_p\,S$ is:
\begin{equation}
    h := \langle\,q - p\,,\,N\,\rangle.
    \label{distance:to:tangent:plane}
\end{equation}
Note that in this way $q - p$ will be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Having in mind that each $\sigma_i:U\subset\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and using the multi-variable Taylor expansion we get
\begin{equation*}
    q - p = \sigma\left(u + du, v + dv\right) - \sigma\left(u, v\right) =\\[1 cm]
\underbrace{ \left(\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}c}
    \frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial u}\,du + \frac{\partial \sigma_1}{\partial v}\,dv\\[0.5 cm] \frac{\partial \sigma_2}{\partial u}\,du + \frac{\partial \sigma_2}{\partial v}\,dv\\[0.5 cm]
    \frac{\partial \sigma_3}{\partial u}\,du + \frac{\partial \sigma_3}{\partial v}\,dv    
    \end{array}\right)}_{\star}
    +\frac{1}{2}\,\underbrace{
    \left(\begin{array}{>{\displaystyle}c}
    \frac{\partial^2\sigma_1}{\partial u^2}\,du^2 + 2\,\frac{\partial^2\sigma_1}{\partial u\,\partial v}\,du\,dv + \frac{\partial^2\sigma_1}{\partial v^2}\,dv^2\\[0.5 cm] 
    \frac{\partial^2\sigma_2}{\partial u^2}\,du^2 + 2\,\frac{\partial^2\sigma_2}{\partial u\,\partial v}\,du\,dv + \frac{\partial^2\sigma_2}{\partial v^2}\,dv^2\\[0.5 cm]
    \frac{\partial^2\sigma_3}{\partial u^2}\,du^2 + 2\,\frac{\partial^2\sigma_2}{\partial u\,\partial v}\,du\,dv + \frac{\partial^2\sigma_3}{\partial v^2}\,dv^2    
    \end{array}\right)}_{\star\star}
    + \dots.
\end{equation*}
Now, in the light of the above equation, $h$ simplifies to ($\star$ disappears due to $N$ being normal to $T_p\,S$):
\begin{equation}
    h = \frac{1}{2}\left(\,\langle\,N\,,\,\sigma_{uu}\,\rangle\,du^2 + \langle\,N\,,\,\sigma_{uv}\,\rangle\,du\,dv + \langle\,N\,,\,\sigma_{vv}\,\rangle\,dv^2\right) + \ldots = \frac{1}{2}\,\mathbf{II}\,(u,v) + \ldots
\end{equation}
Neglecting the higher order terms results in
\begin{equation}
    2\,h = \mathbf{II}\,(u,v).
    \label{eq:dis:2nd:fundamental:form}
\end{equation}
Now, if on $T_p\,S$ we choose the basis ${e_1}$ and ${e_2}$ such that they are the eigenvectors of $dN_p$ then this is equal to thinking of the surface (locally) to be parameterized by curvature lines ($F = f = 0$). This results in $k_1 = e/E$ and $k_2 = g/G$. Hence, $h$ simplifies to
\begin{equation*}
    2\,h = \kappa_1{E}\,du^2 + \kappa_2{G}\,dv^2,
\end{equation*}
where $\kappa_i$ are the principal curvatures. Now, thinking of $\sqrt{E}du$ and $\sqrt{G}dv$ as $x$ and $y$ then you'll see the result is a quadric unless if one of your principal curvatures vanish (parabolic points) or both of them vanish, which gives a planar point.

Now, having in mind that the Dupin indicatrix is the set of points $(x,y)$ fitting into the equation
$$\kappa_1 x^2 + \kappa_2 y^2 = \pm 1$$
you can see the similarity between the two equations. Therefore, the Dupin indicatrix tells you how the surface "behaves" around the point under consideration. You can use this on all regular surfaces to know the local behavior of the surface around a point.

Comment: Ehm, thanks for the answer but could you put an idiot version of this for someone who is not very familiar with all the technical terminology ( I am following the informal tristan needham book)

Comment: @666User666 I think now the answer above should show you how this plane "close enough" to the tangent plane makes the quadric (through neglecting the higher orders of Taylor expansion of the distance h to the tangent plane.)