# Dupin indicatrix' s geometrical interpretation: exercise from Ted Shifrin's notes. Ch. 2.2 exercise 22.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $M$ a regular surface and let $P\in M$ a nonplanar point in $M$. The Dupin indicatrix (DI) is defined to be the conic in $T_P M$ given by the equation $\Pi_ P (v)= 1$. The following problem is from Ted Shifrin's notes (Ch. 2.2 exercise 22c); it gives a geometric interpretation of DI. Here is the problem:

> Suppose $P$ is the origin, and $M$ is, in a neighborhood of $P$, the graph of a smooth function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $z= f(x,y)=\frac{1}{2} (k_1 x^2 +k_2y^2) + R(x,y)$, where $\lim_{x,y\rightarrow 0}\frac{R(x,y)}{x^2+y^2} =0$, i.e. the tangent plane $T_P M$ is the $xy$-plane, and the $x$ and $y$-axes are the principal directions at P. Show that for small positive values of $c$, the intersection of a sufficiently small neighborhood of $M$ with the plane $z = c$ “looks like” the Dupin indicatrix. How can you make this statement more precise?

It is not clear to me what kind of statement is satisfactory here. Here is my result for the case where DI is simply a circle:

Fix $\delta>0$. There exists $\eta>0$ such that the following hold. Inside $B((0,0),\eta)\subseteq U$, we have $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+R(x,y)$, where $|R(x,y)|\le \delta (x^2+y^2)$. Let $0<\epsilon<\eta \sqrt{1-\delta}\ $, and consider $C_\epsilon:=\{(x,y)\in U: \ f(x,y)=\epsilon^2\}$. We denote the circles of radius $r$ by $D_r: = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: \ x^2+y^2=r^2\}$. Then,

1. $C_\epsilon$ is between $D_{\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{1+\delta}}}$, $D_{\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{1-\delta}}}$

Intuitively, we need more than just this to argue that $C_\epsilon$ "looks like" $D_\epsilon$. For example, we would like to know that $C_\epsilon$ is connected. So, I also proved the following:

2. $C_\epsilon$ is a regular curve (in particular, $\epsilon^2$ is a regular value of $f$).
3. There exists $r: [0,2\pi) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$, which is continuous, and such that the curve $\gamma:[0,2\pi)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 $ defined as $\gamma(\theta)=(r(\theta)\cos\theta,r(\theta)\sin\theta )$ has range the $C_\epsilon$, i.e. $\gamma ([0,2\pi))=C_\epsilon.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do we only get conics when we do the Dupin indicatrix procedure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4329377/do-we-only-get-conics-when-we-do-the-dupin-indicatrix-procedure)

Comment: No, because there it is not justified why it makes sense to throw away the terms of order greater than 2. What I have shown for the special case of the circle, justifies exactly this.

Comment: It was the author's intention to offer a thought-provoking challenge (a rigorous proof of which is beyond the scope of the course). The actual proof comes from the Morse Lemma (see, for example, Guillemin and Pollack or Milnor's *Morse Theory*); with that you will get a diffeomorphism between the level set and the Dupin indicatrix. But compliments to you for a serious approach to the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Here is what I understand a (not completely formal) statement should be : for every small enough $\epsilon>0$, take the intersection curve of $M$ with $z=\epsilon$, and "rescale" it. Call the resulting curve $C_\epsilon$. Then, there exists diffeomorphism $\phi_\epsilon$ from D  to $C_\epsilon$, where D is the DI. Also, for every $x\in D$,  $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} || \phi_\epsilon(x) - x|| = 0$.

Comment: Does this make sense? Two questions: 1. what would be a proper definition of "rescaling"? if a point is planar, then this should depend on the order of vanishing derivatives. 2. can the limit, instead of pointwise, be uniform?